# Probability of getting at least one complete set

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Each box of a certain brand of breakfast cereal contains a small charm, with $k$ distinct charms forming a set. Assuming that the chance of drawing any particular charm is equal to that of drawing any other charm, Find the probability of finding at least one complete set of charms in a random purchase of $N \ge k$ boxes.

My attempt:
Let $x_i$ denotes the number of occurrences of $i^{th}$ charm in N boxes. Therefore,
$$ x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k = N$$
since we are looking for probability of atleast one complete set. So,
$x_i \ge 1$. Thus,
$$ x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_k = N-k ; x_i \ge 0$$
Solution to the problem can be found out by caculating number of distinct solutions of the above equation.
Please check if my logic is correct.

Comment: The question does not quite ask 'In how many distinct ways can one find a complete set of charms in a random purchase of $N\geq k$ boxes?', which is what your solution answers.

Comment: Can you give any idea to approach the problem?

Comment: I can think of Inclusion-Exclusion, but perhaps there is a niftier way.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not looking for the expected count.

You are looking for the *probability* of finding *at least one* of *every* of $k$ charms in $N$ boxes when the probability of finding any particular charm in any particular box is $1/k$.   (N>k)

Let $X$ be the count of charms you *don't* find and use the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.

$$\mathsf P(X=0) ~ = ~ \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} (-1)^j \mathsf P(X\geq j)$$

Comment: I feel like it should be possible to obtain a closed form solution. Do you think it will get messy, or why did you leave it where you did?

Comment: @Lovsovs Some work should be left for the student.  It comes to a neat summation for which there is not *exactly* a closed form.  It does, however, equal a reasonably well known expression involving [Stirling Number of the Second Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html)

Comment: Okay. Personally, I'd like to see how to arrive at an expression for $P(X\geq j)$.. it seems very complicated to me (I'm thinking along [these](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9513/102680) lines and I think that is the wrong approach), and perhaps also to OP? But no pressure to give such an expression if you deem your current answer more pedagogically justified :)

Comment: @Graham Please explain how did you reach the final statement. And where did you use the exclusion-inclusion principle?